# EmitIL - Call method with ref parameter

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I am trying to write the Following code in MSIL:

```
class ReferenceTestViewModel : BaseViewModel, ITestViewModel
{
    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref id, value); }
    }
}
```

`SetProperty` being a method of its grand-father `BaseObservable` (`BaseViewModel : BaseObservable`).

So I compiled this `ReferenceTestViewModel` and use ILSpy to get the following IL:

```
.field private int32 id

.method public final hidebysig specialname newslot virtual 
    instance void set_Id (
        int32 'value'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x230c
    // Code size 21 (0x15)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldarg.0
    IL_0003: ldflda int32 ReferenceTestViewModel::id
    IL_0008: ldarg.1
    IL_0009: ldstr "Id"
    IL_000e: call instance void [OtherAssembly]BaseObservable::SetProperty<int32>(!!0&, !!0, string)
    IL_0013: nop
    IL_0014: ret
} // end of method ReferenceTestViewModel::set_Id
```

And I finally end-up with the Following C# generator code. Before reading it, please take into account that my whole class was working fine before my attempt to call the `SetProperty` method. It was just setting the associated backing field (cf my comment: Old way), but it was working just fine. So I am pretty sur the error is in that part.

```
private static void GenerateSetter(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType, PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder, FieldBuilder backingFieldBuilder)
{
    MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr =
        typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
          MethodAttributes.Public
        | MethodAttributes.SpecialName
        | MethodAttributes.HideBySig
        | MethodAttributes.Final
        | MethodAttributes.Virtual
        | MethodAttributes.NewSlot,
          null,
          new[] { propertyType });

    ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

    // New way : call SetProperty
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldflda, backingFieldBuilder);
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, propertyName);
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(BaseViewModel).GetMethod(nameof(BaseObservable.SetProperty), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    // Old way : simply set the backing field and return
    //setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    //setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    //setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, backingFieldBuilder);
    //setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
}
```

For information, here is how I build the backing field and the property:

```
private static void GenerateProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType, ConstructorBuilder ctorBuilder)
{
    var fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);
    var propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);

    GenerateGetter(typeBuilder, propertyBuilder, fieldBuilder);
    GenerateSetter(typeBuilder, propertyName, propertyType, propertyBuilder, fieldBuilder);
}

private static void InitializeProperty(Type propertyType, ConstructorBuilder ctorBuilder, FieldBuilder fieldBuilder)
{
    var propertyCtor = propertyType.GetConstructors().First();
    var emitIL = ctorBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    emitIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    emitIL.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, propertyCtor);
    emitIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
}

private static void GenerateGetter(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder, FieldBuilder backingFieldBuilder)
{
    MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        "get_" + propertyBuilder.Name,
        MethodAttributes.Public
        | MethodAttributes.SpecialName
        | MethodAttributes.HideBySig
        | MethodAttributes.Final
        | MethodAttributes.Virtual
        | MethodAttributes.NewSlot,
        propertyBuilder.PropertyType,
        Type.EmptyTypes);

    ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

    getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, backingFieldBuilder);
    getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
}
```

And finally, here is the failing test:

```
var testObject = (ITestViewModel)Activator.CreateInstance(_dynamicType); 

var value = testObject.Id; // works fine
testObject.Id = 42; // throw BadImageFormatException
```

Here is the stacktrace :

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)
>
> at DynamicITestViewModel.set_Id(Int32 )

Comment: Is it feasible to reduce huge example to couple of relevant lines of code to get a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: I would recommend having a deeper look at `testObject.Id = 42;` line as compiled from C# by Roslyn to create a working baseline and use raw IL and metadata to analyze it - do not rely on ILSpy and it's bugs to guide you in your work.

Comment: Save the generated module and run peverify on it. I don't see it in your code but it seems you are implementing an interface so at some point you must call TypeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(...) on the getter and setter methods.

Comment: @elchido: Shane Delany's answer solves my issue but thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know about peverify (I actually don't know much about MSIL ^^) and I will take a look about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it's to do with `SetProperty` being a generic method.

The current call instruction is being emitted using a non-typed generic method reference so it would essentially be a call to `SetProperty<T>(ref id, value)` rather than `SetProperty<Int32>(ref id, value)`.

Modifying the call emit to use the typed generic version of the method (using `.MakeGeneric(typeof(int))`) should fix it.

I.E.

```
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(BaseViewModel).GetMethod(nameof(BaseObservable.SetProperty), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).MakeGeneric(typeof(int)));
```

rather than

```
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(BaseViewModel).GetMethod(nameof(BaseObservable.SetProperty), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
```